# Solving simultaneous ODEs with NDSolve causes unexpected singularity error (ndsz)

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to model the evaporation of a binary droplet in a square well by solving a couple of PDEs for its height profile and composition. I can manage it for a single liquid pretty well, but when I introduce the PDE for composition NDSolve quickly finds a singularity in the composition variable (importantly the singularity moves slightly if I change the number of points). I can't seem to find any way to stabilise the system, can anyone help me? Is there something fundamental about NDSolve that I'm missing?

(I asked a similar question a while ago but I've restructured my code to make it easier to share here)

The equations are:

$$
 \frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = - C \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big[\frac{1}{3} \frac{\partial^3h}{\partial x^3}h^3 + \frac{B}{2} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x}\Big]  - (1-AX)
$$
$$
 \frac{\partial X}{\partial t} = -\frac{C}{3} h^2 \frac{\partial^3h}{\partial x^3}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} - \frac{hB}{2} \Big(\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}\Big)^2 + \frac{A}{h}X(1-X)
$$

with height $h$ and composition $X$.

And the boundary conditions are

$h(t)=1$ and $X(t)=X(t=0)$ at $x=1$, $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}=0$ at $x=0$, and $\frac{\partial^3h}{\partial x^3}=0$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

I discretise all this using finite differences.

This is what I get for a single liquid droplet (when I suppress equation 2) and I expect something qualitatively similar for a binary droplet.
[image: Droplet curves when the composition equation is suppressed]

Here is a minimum replicable example:

```
    N1 = 100; dx = 1/N1; (*Discretise*)
    C1  = 1; (*parameter C*)
    a = 1.5; b = 1 - a; hInitial = Table[a + b i^2 dx^2, {i, 0, N1}]; (*Initial height profile*)
    E1 = 1;(*evaporation on/off switch*)
    Cc = C1/(24 * dx^3);
    A1 = 0.01; B1 = 1;  (*Control constants in the equations above*)
    CcX = (C1 B1)/(2 dx^2); CcX2 = C1/(6 dx^2);
    X0 = 0.4; XInitial = Table[X0, {i, 0, N1}]; (*Initial composition ratio*)
    Sc = 1; (*Composition on/off switch*)
    TGap = 0.085;(*for spacing curves in the plot*)



     dv[v_List] :=
      With[{h = Take[v, Length[v]/2 - 1], hN = v[[(Length[v]/2)]], 
        X1 = v[[Length[v]/2 + 1 ;; Length[v] - 1]], XN = v[[-1]]},
       With[{
         dh1 = 
          ListCorrelate[{0, 0, 1 , 1, 0}, #] &, (*derivatives are discretised as finite differences. 
          ListCorrelate achieves this.*)

         dh2 = ListCorrelate[{0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, #] &,
         dh3 = ListCorrelate[{0, -1, 3, -3, 1}, #] &,
         dh4 = ListCorrelate[{-1, 3, -3, 1, 0}, #] &,
         hi = ListCorrelate[{0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, #] &,
         dh5 = ListCorrelate[{-1, 2, 0, -2, 1}, #] &,
 
         dx1 = ListCorrelate[{0, -1, 1}, #] &,
         dx2 = ListCorrelate[{-1, 1, 0}, #] &,
         Xi = ListCorrelate[{0, 1, 0}, #] &
         },
        Flatten@{
            -Cc*(dh1[#1]^3*dh3[#1] - dh2[#1]^3*dh4[#1]) -  
            CcX*(dh1[#1]^2*dx1[#2] - dh2[#1]^2*dx2[#2]) - 
            E1*(1 - A1 Xi[#2]), (*ODE for heights*)

            0,(*height is pinned at edge, (1, 1)*)

            Sc*(-CcX2* hi[#1]^2*dh5[#1]*dx2[#2] - 
            CcX/C1* hi[#1]*dx2[#2]^2 + 
            A1 *(hi[#1])^-1*Xi[#2]*(1 - Xi[#2])), (*ODE for composition*)
        
            0 (*composition ratio is fixed at edge, XN = 0.4*)
            } &[
         Flatten@Join[{h[[3]]}, {h[[2]]}, {h}, {1}, {3 - 3 h[[-1]] + h[[-2]]}], 
           
         Flatten@Join[{X1[[2]]}, {X1}, {XN}]]]

              (*this contains the boundary conditions*)

       ];

    v0 = Join[hInitial, XInitial]; (*Initial conditions*)
    system2d = 
     NDSolve[{v'[t] == dv[v[t]], v[0] ==  v0,

        WhenEvent[
         Min@Table[
            Take[values[[tt]], Length[values[[tt]]]/2], 
             {tt, 1,  Length[values]}] < 0, 
         "StopIntegration"](*WhenEvent to stop integration at touchdown*)}, 

       v, {t, 0, 2}][[1, 1, 2]];


    Needs@"DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`";
    values = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid@system2d; 
    times = Flatten@InterpolatingFunctionGrid@system2d;

    T1 = 0; timesteps = {}; For[i = 1, i < Length[times], i++, 
     If[times[[i]] > T1, {T1 = T1 + TGap, 
       timesteps = Append[timesteps, {i, times[[i]]}]}]];
    finaltime = {{-1}}; firstandfinaltime = {{1}, {-1}};

    heights = 
      Table[Take[values[[tt]], Length[values[[tt]]]/2], 
        {tt, 1, Length[values]}];

    comps = Table[
       Take[values[[tt]], -(Length[values[[tt]]]/2)],  
        {tt, 1, Length[values]}];

    Show[Table[
      ListPlot[Table[{i*dx, heights[[ttt[[1]], i + 1]]}, {i, 0, N1}], 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1.05*a}}, Joined -> True, 
       AxesLabel -> {x, h}], {ttt, finaltime}]]

    Show[Table[
      ListPlot[Table[{i*dx, comps[[ttt[[1]], i + 1]]}, {i, 0, N1}], 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Joined -> True,
       AxesLabel ->{x, X}], {ttt, finaltime}]]
```

Thank you for any help you can offer me!